# Find texture by format?

Tags: unity

One of our testers on Linux reported long load times. In looking through the player log, I noticed that there are several errors about BC7 textures:

```
WARNING: RGBA Compressed BC7 UNorm format is not supported, decompressing texture
```

Is there an easy way to search a Unity project to find textures that are compressed in a particular format? I tried making a build and searching the Editor log afterward, but the build log doesn't reference the specific texture formats.

Comment: Can you re-import them with [platform specific overrides](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html#platform)?

Comment: @Pikalek The problem is that there are hundreds of textures in the project and I don't know _which textures_ use BC7. The warning in the log does not mention the texture name.

Comment: I realize this doesn't tell you which individual files are problematic. I was asking if you could set the overrides such that the linux build used some other acceptable format & re-import all the textures under the modified settings.

Comment: @Pikalek I can't simply override all the textures at once because different textures require different formats (e.g. alpha, no-alpha, normal map, etc). I need to find the specific textures that use BC7 and override those.